# facial expression classification using k-means

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, face-detection, feature-detection

My method for classifying facial expressions using k-means is:

1. Use opencv to detect the face in the image
2. Use ASM and stasm to get the facial feature point
3. Calculate the distance between facial features (as show in the picture). There'll be 5 distances. [image]
4. Calculate the centroid for each distance for each facial expression (exp: in the distance D1 there are 7 centroids for each expression 'happy, angry...').
5. Use 5 k-means each k-means for a distance and each k-means will have as a result the expression shown by the distance closest to the Centroid calculated in the first step.
6. Final expression will be the expression that appears in the most k-means results

However, using that method my results are wrong?
Is my method correct or is it wrong somewhere?

Comment: Consider using classification instead of clustering.

Comment: I would go with classification as well, but if you wanna try you could see how k-means performs using the 5 features all together and finding the centroids in a 5-dimension space.

Comment: Did you ever plot your data to see whether it is separable? Since it's hard to plot 5 dimensional data, I suggest to run a PCA and plot the first three principal components of the different expressions so see whether they are actually separable. In case they are overlapping, you have to think of a new way to represent your data. It's really hard to say what is the optimal way of representing facial expressions so why not using deep belief to find answer this question algorithmically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

K-means is not a classification algorithm. Once runned, it simply finds centroids of K elements, so it splits data into K parts, but in most cases it won't have anything to do with desired classes. This algorithm (as all the clustering methods) should be used when you want to **explore** data and find some distinguishable objects. Distinguishable in **any** sense. If your task is to build a system, which recognizes some **given** classes, then it is a **[classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_%28machine_learning%29)** problem, not **[clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)**. One of the most simple methods, which are easy to both implement and understand is [KNN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) (K-nearest neighbours), which roughly does what you are trying to accomplish - checks which classes' objects are the closest ones to some predefined ones.

To better see the difference let us consider your case - you are trying to detect emotional state based on the face features. Running k-means on such data can split your face photos into many groups:

- If you use photos of different people, it can cluster photos of particular people together (as their distances differ from others)
- it can split data into for example man and woman, as there are gender specific differences in such features
- it can even split your data based on the distance from the camera, as the perspective changes your features, creating "clusters".
- etc.

As you can see, there are dozens possible "reasonable" (and even more completely not interpretable) splits, and K-means (and **any**) other clustering algorithm will simply find one of them (in most cases - the not interpretable one). Classification methods are used to overcome this issue, to "explain" the algorithm what are you expecting.